# Render the PostGIS OSM data in 3d?

Tags: openstreetmap, 3d, rendering

I wonder is there any open-source application that can query a PostGIS-enabled database and render the resulting OSM map in 3d.

The only thing I have found so far is [Navit](http://www.navit-project.org/), but it renders only from an .osm file, but not a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can render from POSTGIS with OSM data in 3D

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM-3D

[image]

NOTE:
*"Preparing OSM data to be viewed in OSM-3D requires a lot of preprocessing steps which are done on GIScience's servers."*

see the ZIMBA server
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM-3D#Servers

Comment: Seems very complicated. Have you had a chance to try this: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ShugenDoMap ?

Comment: Martin it is only a proof of concept, there is no source code (yet). With any 3D data there will be high overheads either hardware or very clever software rendering. Think of the many games out there now and the millions it takes to achieve high quality graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest my new project: osm2x3d.
My code is c++. It transforms osm data (xml) to x3D data (xml).
Source code available here:https://github.com/clement-igonet/osm2x3d
I'm currently coding it again but in javascript for à better support. Several format Will be supported like geojson for an exploitation by osmbuildings project.

Comment: Could you add some links you consider useful?

Comment: The demo web site is here: http://web.osm2x3d.net

Comment: I just approved an anonymous edit to this answer that appeared to be from its original author.  It is far better,  if you can log in to make direct edits yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS threejs plugin is able to turn OSM data into 3D:

http://www.cartografia.cl/beta/index.php/home/sig/891-generar-edificaciones-en-3d-a-partir-de-un-shapefile-con-qgis

Another chance is povray:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Maxbe/Relief_mit_POVray
http://blog.openstreetmap.de/blog/2012/01/wochennotiz-nr-80/

You might need Google translate to understand the text

Also promising: http://bitsteller.bplaced.net/osm/ but I have not tested it myself.